# How to add image and text in UITextField as placeholder in center in swift

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift2

I am new to Swift so bear with me I want to add an image and text as horizontal align centered in the `UITextField`. Using following code I was able to add image in the textbox but it is in center and also it remains there when textbox gets focus. I want it in center with placeholder text and when `UITextField` gets focus it hides.

```
var imageView = UIImageView()
var image = UIImage(named: "all.png")
imageView.image = image
searchFiled.leftView = imageView
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not 'speak' Swift, but it should be easily possible to translate the Objective-C version...

Your talking about the so-called 'placeholder'; the string (or attributed string), that is shown in the **UITextField**, when no really text is inserted.

To show an image here use the following code:

```
    // Create a NSTextAttachment with your image
    NSTextAttachment*   placeholderImageTextAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    placeholderImageTextAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your image name"];

    // Use 'bound' to adjust position and size
    placeholderImageTextAttachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16);
    NSMutableAttributedString*  placeholderImageString = [[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:placeholderImageTextAttachment] mutableCopy];

    // Append the placeholder text
    NSMutableAttributedString*  placeholderString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Search", nil)];
    [placeholderImageString appendAttributedString:placeholderString];

    // set as (attributed) placeholder
    _yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderImageString;
```

Comment: The question was asked about Swift syntax. You've provided Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

If by focus, you mean the user clicks on the UITextField, then what you want is to have your view controller act as a UITextFieldDelegate.  You want to implement the optional func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) function.  In that function you want to hide the image.